# Using jetty to install and run servlet tests programmatically

Tags: java, servlets

The jetty servlet container is quick and light enough to run in unit tests (indeed I do to serve up files).

It is possible to install actual servlets into it, programmatically (say in a test) and have it run them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. We do this on a regular basis with a number of tools. The simpest is probably [HTTP-unit](http://www.httpunit.org/doc/servletunit-intro.html). When we deploy in jetty, we usually deploy larger parts of the application and run [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). HttpUnit is the simplest, but at some point your application complexity may warrant a more complete deployment. See the documentation section on [embedding jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/embedding-jetty.html)

Comment: Hey wow thanks - that was exactly what I was looking for - didn't really know what to search for (tried a few things - never thought to search for "embedded").

Answer (score 1):

Why not use any HttpUnit, [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) etc.. Create an ANT script to do whatever is needed to run the test.

Comment: Oh I have things like that - I just would like to wire it all up in code - no external scripts to run - less likely to fail (as long as the port is free).