# Loading up a web.xml for integration tests with jetty

Tags: java, jvm, jetty

OK this is kind of related to : [Using jetty to install and run servlet tests programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728805/using-jetty-to-install-and-run-servlet-tests-programmatically)

got great answers there, and have been able to load up servlets programmatically and its all made of awesome.

What I would like to do however is load up a web.xml in a test (all in the classpath) and have it run up a server (using the current classpath) - I have seen in docs how to point it to a directory to do that, but I want to work off the classpath (better for in place testing). Essentially validating my web.xml.

(its not relevant, but this app is in scala, but I have had no issue with that, everything works as advertised).

Comment: I dont see your problem - what do you mean with "all in the classpath"? As i understand you would like to start a Jetty with a certain web.xml. This should be no problem, copy the web.xml with a script and start the Jetty.

Comment: Actually I want it to run with tests - not start it up as a separate process (which works fine, but its not as tidy as an inprocess unit test) - its just a convenience thing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is load a proper web application programatically, as opposed to loading individual servlets (and I think you want to do it without having a full WAR file to work from).

```
Server server = new Server( port );
WebAppContext root = new WebAppContext();

root.setWar("/path/to/somewhere");
root.setContextPath("/");

server.addHandler( root );
server.start();
```

The trick is that the `/path/to/somewhere` should contain a `WEB-INF` directory and your `web.xml` file should live inside there. Nothing else needs to live within that directory structure, as everything else can be automatically loaded from your classpath (though if you wanted to, you could make that a path to an actual WAR file or complete exploded WAR tree).

Comment: (and its fast ! great for "unit" tests which are really more then unit tests !) - thanks for updating this post BTW.